# Integrate Facebook within an application and show activity on my web site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have an application where a user can create a record of data and during this process share their entry on their timeline.  I would then like to have an element on my web page such as an IFRAME list that shows the activity of all those that are sharing their posts using my application.  For example, my application is a pilot's logbook so every flight they fly they post the flight to their timeline using the app.  I then want to have a central list that shows all of the activity from all the users sharing their flights.  It shows how many people and how actively the software is being used.  I already have my iPhone app posting to Facebook so I have the "connect" feature implemented, now how can I aggregate the information to show the posting activity on my web site?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems simple enough, are you storing the post data or id's via a mysql database?

Comment: I'm not storing anything, should I be?  I simply use the open graph to post to the timeline "feed" using the app I created on Facebook so the iPhone app (and soon Android) can connect to it.  Wasn't sure if the use of the facebook app can be aggregated into a real time list on the web site? I want to show Facebook activity using the app.

Comment: with the complicated permission sets, it would be simplest, and fastest to store each post_id, uid, and time in a mysql database as they are made.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need the activity plugin.
Look here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/

You can then summarize the activities you want to list in the feed by using the action attribute :

```
<fb:activity 
site="jerrycain.com"
action="critiqueapp:despise,critiqueapp:review,critiqueapp:grade">
</fb:activity>
```